# Why does my while loop needs this line of code to run?

Tags: java, file, io, while-loop

I just completed an application which prompts the user for a text `File` input `IO` but I have something to clarify as the final part, `While loop` I actually managed to refer it to a tutorial on google. In this loop, there is a `if-else` statement and for the else part I don't understand why is it necessary.

Here's my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class FileReadingExercise2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner fileInput = null;

        do {
            try {
                System.out.println("Please enter the name of a file or type QUIT to finish");
                String a = userInput.nextLine();

                if (a.equals("QUIT")) { // if user inputs QUIT then stop application
                    System.exit(0);
                }

                fileInput = new Scanner(new File(a)); // the file contains text and integers
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                System.out.println("Error - File not found");
            }
        } while (fileInput == null);

        int sum = 0;

        while (fileInput.hasNext()) // continues loop as long as there is a next token
        {
            if (fileInput.hasNextInt()) // if there is an int on the next token
            {
                sum += fileInput.nextInt(); // then adds the int to the sum
            } else {
                fileInput.next(); // else go to the next token
            }
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
        fileInput.close();
    }
}
```

As you can see, as long as the **fileInput** `Scanner` has a next token to look up to then operate the if else statement. If **fileInput** has a next `Int` then adds it up to the **sum** variable. So from what I think is that this will be sufficient. Once **fileInput** has no more token to read, it shall get out of the `while loop` isn't it? Why does it has still go onto the next token? I'm confused. Please advise thanks! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Why does it has still go onto the next token?
```

That is because when `nextInt()` is executed it will consume the `int number` within the file but within it, it has a `newLine` character that needs to be consume and that is when `next` is executed to consume that `newLine` after the `int number`.

sample file content:

```
1
```

what actually in there is `1` character and newline `\n` character

Comment: @Scorpiorian83 each end of the file has new Line character within them. and that character is comsumed by `next` method if the scanner go and read the documentation of it.

Comment: oh ok I get what you try to explain now thanks so much but the part I still don't get it is in the `while loop`, all it has to do is to go through each token of the file and if it's an int then add up to the sum but why would we need to setup the else statement there?

Comment: @Scorpiorian83 to makre sure that you wont go in an infinite loop. because when you dont consume the new Line then no one will thus going to a loop, you can try it actually, remove it and see the result.

Comment: oic but when I tried to remove the else part, the application doesn't work at all lol.

Comment: @Scorpiorian83 yes that is because you dont consume the `newLine`. after the number.

Answer (score 1):

```
In this loop, there is a if-else statement and for the else part I don't understand 
why is it necessary.
```

fileInput.hasNexInt() method returns true if int value found and than it performs adding operation. if next value is not int type than else part will perform where fileInput.next() will return next value(pointer will points after that value), performs nothing means escaping next value(which can be any type except int-type). Again if condition will check for int.

Comment: oic with both yours and Rod's explanation I get it more thanks! :D

Comment: oic  means what? @Scorpiorian83